# can not insert vue-router tag inside link

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vuejs app where I allow users to register and become members. 
I added `vuex` to store messages related to success/failure of the process.

Currently, everything works except when I try to store and show a [vue-router] link inside a variable like this:

```
...
Registration() {
  if(true) {
    this.$store.commit('SET_MESSAGE', {
     type: 'success',
     title: 'Registration Success',
     content: 'please click <router-link to="/profile"> here </router-link> to see your profile'
  }
}
```

Now, I can retrieve all the properties and display them, but the `<router-link to="/profile"> here </router-link>` tag does not transform (or functions) as it is supposed to.

This is how I am displaying it.

```
 <div class="alert alert-dismissible" :class="'alert-' +type"  >
 <h1> {{tilte}} </h1> 
 <p> {{content}} </p>
</div>
```

I tried with `<p v-bind:html='content'></p>` and `{{{ content }}}` the route does not work in either case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML. In
> order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive [DOC](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```
<p v-html="content" />
```

EDIT

In order to make router-link to work you need to use a computed property that return an object of components options:

```
computed: {
  contentComp () {
    return { template: `<p>${this.content}</p>` }
  }
}
```

Then render it:

```
<component :is="contentComp"></component>
```

Final result:

```js
const profile = {
  template: '<div> profile page! </div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/profile',
    component: profile
  }]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Registration Success',
    content: 'please click <router-link to="/profile"> here </router-link> to see your profile'
  },
  computed: {
    contentComp() {
      return {
        template: `<p>${this.content}</p>`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
    <component :is="contentComp"></component>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: this will not work, router-link will actually not get compiled

Comment: Investigating about that

Comment: eh.. i meant v-html instead of v-text... anyway, it does not work .. maybe this is a bug

Comment: [This](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) can really explain better than me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert dynamic content (that is to say content that needs to be compiled, like your `router-link`) with `v-html`, it's only meant for regular html. I suggest an alternate approach, that is to put your `router-link` in the template, but hide it with a `v-if` switch, that way it will be rendered and displayed only once you toggle the switch.

Template

```
<span v-if="displayRouter">
  please click <router-link to="/profile"> here </router-link> to see your profile
</span>
```

JS

```
Registration() {
  if(true) {
    this.displayRouter = true
    ...
```

Generally I believe it's much clearer to keep all the html *in* the html, not in the JS.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but this would mean I have to hard-code a text instead of storing it like I am doing for all other alerts. So, it will only fix a temporary issue but will not solve how to store dynamic content ... hopefully someone know a way around this

Comment: You can still mix this solution with some variables inside the template, but indeed that won't solve the general case.

Answer (score 0):

```
Register () {
  if(ok) {
    this.$store.commit('SET_MESSAGE', {
     type: 'success',
     title: 'Registration Success',
     content: 'please click <a href="/profile"> here </a> to see your profile'
  }
}
```

You can use `<a>` tag.

Comment: you have just changed the router-link tag to a, it won't work anyway